# C++ Left Shift Operation Bit Manipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I am not able to get why it is giving negative after certain point. Also I am using long long to prevent overflow.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    for(long long i=0;i<64;i++){
        cout << 1LL*(1<<i) << " ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 4194304 8388608 16777216 33554432 67108864 134217728 268435456 536870912 1073741824 -2147483648 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 4194304 8388608 16777216 33554432 67108864 134217728 268435456 536870912 1073741824 -2147483648
```

Comment: Try `(1LL << i)` instead of trying to do the `1LL *` after shifting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1 << i
```

..in the above line, `1` is an `int` and i is a `long long`. So to fix your issue you can cast to a `long long` as such:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    for (long long i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        cout << 1LL * (static_cast<long long>(1) << i) << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will allow you to go to higher values.

You can also use `1LL` (`1 long long`) instead of casting:

```
cout << 1LL * (1LL << i) << " ";
```

..with this you can remove `1LL *`:

```
cout << (1LL << i) << " "; // Brakcets are required
```

Comment: Why the `1LL *`? `1LL << 1` is already a long long.

Comment: Also, use `ULL`.  Signed integer overflows have _undefined behavior_.

Comment: For what is allowed and what is undefined and what is Implementation defined, look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic section bitwise shift operators. Shifting signed integers was simplified and defined more strictly (for the compiler vendors) with C++20: Before, for signed numbers you were not allowed to left-shift negative numbers at all or left-shift positive numbers, when one-bits went over the width (but they could overflow from positive to negative). And right-shift of negative numbers was implementation-defined. All those are now clearly defined with C++20

Comment: So signed integer shift of signed 64-bit `1LL` to the left by 0 to 63 bits is defined before C++20 and with C++20 (and such a shift of unsigned `1ULL` anyway). However, shifting a signed *or* unsigned *32-bit* integer by 32 bits or more is undefined with C++20 or before.